# How do you get rsync to exclude any directory named cache?

Tags: directory, rsync

I'm new to rsync and have read a bit about excluding files and directories but I don't fully understand and can't seem to get it working.

I'm simply trying to run a backup of all the websites in a server's webroot but don't want any of the CMS's cache files.

Is there away to exclude any directory named cache?

I've tried a lot of things over the weeks (that I don't remember), but more recently I've been trying these sorts of things:

```
sudo rsync -avzO -e --exclude *cache ssh username@11.22.33.44:/home/ /Users/username/webserver-backups/DEV/home/
```

and this:

```
sudo rsync -avzO -e --exclude cache/ ssh username@11.22.33.44:/home/ /Users/username/webserver-backups/DEV/home/
```

and this:

```
sudo rsync -avzO -e --exclude */cache/ ssh username@11.22.33.44:/home/ /Users/username/webserver-backups/DEV/home/
```

and this:

```
sudo rsync -avzO -e --exclude *cache/ ssh username@11.22.33.44:/home/ /Users/username/webserver-backups/DEV/home/
```

Sorry if this is easy, I just haven't been able to find info that I understand because they all talk about a path to exclude.

It's just that I don't have a specific path I want to exclude - just a directory name if that makes sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
rsync --exclude cache/ ....
```

should work like peaches. I think you might be confusing some things since `-e` requires an option (like `-e "ssh -l ssh-user"`). **Edit** on looking at your command lines a little closer, it turns out this is exactly your problem. You should have said

```
--exclude cache/ -e ssh
```

although you could just drop `-e ssh` since ssh is the default.

---

I'd also recommend that you look at the filter rules:

```
rsync -FF ....
```

That way you can include .rsync-filter files throughout your directory tree, containing things like

```
-cache/
```

This makes things way more flexible, make command lines more readable and you can make exceptions inside specific subtrees.

Comment: Thanks for that.

So to test, I removed the -e option and tried cache/ like this

`sudo rsync -avzO --exclude cache/ ssh username@11.22.33.4:/home/ /Users/username/webserver-backups/LIVE/home/`

But because of the trailing slash on cache/ rsync thinks ssh is a directory and I get an error:

`/Users/username/ssh failed: No such file or directory`

Comment: @CMSCSS: that's your problem right there. DO NOT SPLIT `-e` and `ssh`. Like I said, ssh goes with `-e`. Although, when the shell is `ssh`, you can just drop the `-e ssh` option altogether, since it is the default

Comment: OK Thanks for that - I now understand! So this now works: `sudo rsync -avzO -e "ssh -l remote-username" --exclude cache/ 11.22.33.44:/home/ /Users/local-username/webserver-backups/DEV/home/` Cheers!